QGIS 3.36.2 issue: datasource not found (localized)
When opening a .qgz-file with QGIS 3.36.2, which was saved with previous versions (3.30.3 or 3.32.2), all the datasources of layers, saved in another directory than the .qgz-file, get lost. In the handle unavailable layers dialogue the datasrouces start with localized:
I have never had this issue before, when upgrading to a new QGIS-version.
Does anyone know why and how I can fix this?
Edit: Luckily the missing datasource always lies in the same directory for all the .qgz-files. Therefore, adding this path to Localized Data Paths (Settings -> Options -> Data Sources) solved the problem for all the .qgz-files.
Still, I don’t know why this happened and how I can go back to not localized data paths.
